# Chromatic number of random spanning subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, random-graphs, probabilistic-method

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with chromatic number $χ(G)=k>4$, let $G'=(V,E')$ be a spanning subgraph of $G$, created by picking each edge of $E$ with probability $1/2$.

How can I show that there is a constant $c>0$ such that $χ(G')≤2$ with probability less than $2^{{-ck^2}}$?

As a first step, how can I show that for $k=5$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k=5$ (or any other fixed $k$), since we can choose $c$ to be anything we like, we just need some bound on the probability independent of the number of vertices.

In fact, we can show that the probability is at most $\frac12$, once we prove the following lemma:

> Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be graphs on the same vertex set, and let $H_1 \cup H_2$ be the graph obtained by taking all edges present in either $H_1$ or $H_2$. Then $\chi(H_1 \cup H_2) \le \chi(H_1) \cdot \chi(H_2)$.

**Proof:** Given an $r_i$-coloring $f_i$ of $H_i$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$, we can construct an $r_1r_2$-coloring of $H_1 \cup H_2$ by giving $v$ the color $(f_1(v), f_2(v))$. If $v$ and $w$ are adjacent in $H_1 \cup H_2$, either they're adjacent in $H_1$ (and $f_1(v) \ne f_1(w)$) or they're adjacent in $H_2$ (and $f_2(v) \ne f_2(w)$), so in either case we have $(f_1(v), f_2(v)) \ne (f_1(w), f_2(w))$.

Given a spanning subgraph $G'$ of $G$, if we let $G''$ be the graph formed by taking all edges of $G$ not in $G'$, then $4 < \chi(G) \le \chi(G') \cdot \chi(G'')$, so either $\chi(G') > 2$ or $\chi(G'') > 2$. So we've divided all possible graphs into pairs where at least one graph has chromatic number more than $2$, which means that $\Pr[\chi(G') \le 2]$ is at most $\frac12$.

---

To use this to get the general bound we want, it's enough to partition the edge set $E$ into $\Omega(k^2)$ disjoint parts $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_t$, such that $\chi(G_{E_i}) \ge 5$ for all $i$. Then for a randomly chosen $E' \subseteq E$, $\chi(G_{E'}) \le 2$ only if $\chi(G_{E' \cap E_i}) \le 2$ for all $i$. These are $t$ independent events with probability at most $\frac12$ by the argument above, so $\Pr[\chi(G_{E'}) \le 2] \le 2^{-t}$.

To find $E_1, \dots, E_t$, fix a $k$-coloring $f$ of $G$, and consider sets $V_{abcde} = f^{-1}(\{a,b,c,d,e\})$ for some colors $a, b, c, d, e$. It's not hard to see that if we let $E_{abcde}$ be the set of all edges between pairs of vertices in $V_{abcde}$, then $\chi(G_{E_{abcde}}) = 5$; we have $E_{abcde} \cap E_{a'b'c'd'e'} = \varnothing$ if at most one color is shared between $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $\{a',b',c',d',e'\}$.

So it remains to choose $\Omega(k^2)$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ of size $5$ among which no two share more than one element, which can be done probabilistically using a first moment calculation.

Comment: It's clear to my why there are Ω(k^2) subsets of {1,..,k} of size 5 among which no two share more than one element (pick Ω(k) distinct groups of size 4, and from each group create Ω(k) other groups by adding some random element), however it's not clear to me how to do that in a probabilistic way. What is your idea?

Comment: My idea that since there are at least $C_1 k^5$ subsets of size $5$, and at most $C_2 k^8$ pairs of them that overlap in two or more places, we can sample with a probability of $\frac{\epsilon}{k^3}$ of taking each subset. Then, whenever we took two subsets in an overlapping pair, delete one of them. This leaves at least $(C_1 \epsilon - C_2 \epsilon^2) k^2$ subsets, in expectation. Take $\epsilon < \frac{C_1}{C_2}$ and that's $\Omega(k^2)$ subsets.

Answer (score 1):

A related result is shown in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.04319.pdf.
See Theorem 1.4